# Is there a way of using the R approx function where the values to interpolate over are dependent on other columns in the data frame?

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I want to use the approx function to add a pct_answer column to my table called 'data' in the example below. The pct_answer column is calculated by linearly interpolating from the table called 'lookup'.

The values to interpolate over are dependent on the value of 'account' and 'pattern_number' in the table called data.

I've managed to produce the answer I require by creating a function and then using purrr::map to apply this function across all rows of the data frame (see the reproducible example below). However in the real problem I'm trying to solve there are millions of  rows in the data and this takes an extremely long time to run.

Is there a faster way of achieving the same result?

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(
  account = c(rep("a", 5), rep("b", 7), rep("c", 7)),
  pattern_num = c(rep(1, 2), rep(2, 3), rep(1, 11), rep(2, 3)),
  pct_lookup = c(seq(0.05, 0.25, by = 0.05), seq(0.5, 0.8, by = 0.05), seq(0.65, 0.95, by = 0.05))
)

lookup <- tibble(
  account = c(rep("a", 20), rep("b", 10)),
  pattern_num = c(rep(1, 10), rep(2, 10), rep(1, 10)),
  pct_lookup = rep(seq(0.1, 1, by = 0.1), 3),
  norm_mean = c(rep(0, 10), rep(0.5, 10), rep(0.25, 10))
) %>% 
  mutate(pct_answer = map2_dbl(pct_lookup, norm_mean, pnorm)) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-norm_mean)

lookup_function <- function(account_name, pattern_number, lookup_num){
  
  lookup_table <- lookup %>% 
    filter(account == {{account_name}}, pattern_num == {{pattern_number}})
  
  if(nrow(lookup_table) == 0){
    return(NA)
  }else{
  
  result <- approx(lookup_table$pct_lookup, lookup_table$pct_answer, xout = lookup_num, ties = "ordered", rule = 2)$y
  
  return(result)
  }
}

data <- data %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(pct_answer = map2(account, pattern_num, lookup_function, lookup_num = pct_lookup))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `data.table` approach :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[, pct_answer := mapply(lookup_function, account, pattern_num, pct_lookup)]
data
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Map`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, pct_answer := unlist(Map(lookup_function, account, pattern_num, pct_lookup)])
```